# SQL Index for DISTINCT and WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a mysql database with 6 million records. Here is a sample query I want to execute, but it's taking a lot of time:

```
SELECT DISTINCT company_name 
FROM contacts 
WHERE job_level = 'Manager' AND total_employees > 50
```

What index should I create for such query? I tried Index (job_level, total_employees, company_name) but it's not working.

I didn't find the answer here yet. People are asking for index for `distinct` without `where` clause. I know it can help with creating an sql `view`. But what about such queries with `where` clause?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function. I would suggest you remove the parenthesis for clarity.

Comment: What do you mean "I tried Index (job_level, total_employees, company_name) **but it's not working**." What specifically isn't working?

Comment: @gbeaven the query is slower.

Comment: Please include the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

For your query, I would recommend an index on: `contracts(job_level, total_employees, company_name)`.

That said, if you have a separate table of companies (which seems like a good idea), I would instead recommend:

```
SELECT co.company_name
FROM companies co
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM contacts c
              WHERE c.company_name = co.company_name AND
                    c.job_level = 'Manager' and
                    c.total_employees > 50
             );
```

(The join would be better on `company_id`, if that is available.)

This can then use an index on `contacts(company_name, job_level, total_employees)`.